# parsing nested javascript objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm a little confused about javascript objects. I have a react app and I and I am trying to populate an input with some props. When I console log them out I am able to see them to a point.

This is the structure:

```
{ project: { frameRange: { start: 1000, stop: 1500 } }
```

When I log

```
console.log('this.props.project.frameRange', this.props.project.frameRange);
```

I see:

> this.props.project.frameRange {end: "1048", start: "1000"}
>   end:"1048"    start:"1000"

When I log

```
console.log('this.props.project.frameRange', this.props.project.frameRange.start);
```

I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

What's going on here? I feel like I misunderstanding something fundamental about JS

Comment: You should see a little `i` next to the logged value that says “Value below was evaluated just now”.

Comment: Are the single quotes around `'this.props.project.displayName'` intentional? This will output a string rather than your property.

Comment: I saw the suggested post when I first started dealing with this, but I still don't know how to approach dealing with the situation.